# Change asterisk voicemail settings based on a schedule?

Tags: asterisk, voip, telephony

I need to set up an asterisk voicemail inbox that:

- Works normally during business hours.
- After business hours, calls to this line go straight to voicemail after a special "we're not in right now" recording plays.

I think it should be possible to set the recording using custom time zones, but I'm not sure that is the best way to do it. I also don't know how to control "rings before voicemail" based on a schedule. Is this possible?

Comment: Really should be asked in the asterisk forums or IRC channels whatever they have for support.

Comment: Are asterisk questions not allowed here? If not, why is there an asterisk tag?

Comment: You misunderstood. See how no one replied and commented more? Precisely for that I suggested better venues. Asterisk is not mainstream knowledge, this is why you are better off asking elsewhere.